# Windows 10 Pro 1803: can't share internet to the LAN interface

Tags: networking, internet-sharing, usb-modem, windows-10-v1803

i have this scheme: 

`huawei modem (WAN) -------> USB - WinPC - LAN --> OtherPC LAN`

I want to share internet from modem to pc... and now with no luck.

When i connect LAN to WinPC - i'm losing internet at all. I think that system uses tries to use LAN for internet access... I tried to change metrics:
USB set to 1, LAN set to 30. No luck.

Some screens of `Network Connections`:

LAN is off:
[image: lan_off]
Lan is on:
[image: lan_on]
[image: lan_on_huawei_properties_sharing]

How i can connect LAN and share internet with it?

ps. i've read similar questions: [1](https://superuser.com/questions/760633/2-network-interfaces-route-lan-to-interface-1-internet-to-interface-2), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/459888/how-to-share-internet-using-usb-dongle-on-windows-vista), [3](https://superuser.com/questions/241651/setting-up-wifi-router-as-a-switch-for-internet-connection-sharing). But it doesn't help.

Comment: You seem to be trying to use a Huawei phone as a hotspot, which is not that simple. Try it the other way: 1) Disable Huawei, 2) Enable Ethernet, 3) Enable Huawei. You must first give all devices a static IP address within the same segment, including the Huawei phone.

Comment: i don't have a huawei phone. it is 3g modem aka dongle.