# Sharing Internet connection to other devices through a router

Tags: linux, internet, connection, sharing

I got a Raspberry pi which is connected to router's wan port. Another win7 computer is connected to the router's lan port. 
I tether my phone to raspberry and want to share its connection to the other devices.

I first tried it other way around (windows pc sharing the connection)  using the instructions posted on here :
[Setting up wifi router as a switch for Internet Connection Sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/241651/setting-up-wifi-router-as-a-switch-for-internet-connection-sharing?newreg=f85817bf5a324efda93c22a7f44f6254)

I followed those instructions except that I'm using the raspberry. I believe everything is correct so far, I just need to set up the equivalent for the tap in Windows 7  "Allow other network users to connect through this computer's Internet connection."

How do I do that in Linux?

Answer (score -1):

You need to configure Masquerading using IPtables in RasberryPi. In this your outgoing interface will be your USB connection where Phone is connected.

Have a look at this link, on setting up a [simple Linux Box as a Router and Firewall](http://neeleshgurjar.co.in/techidnyan/making_a_linux_box_as_simple_router_and_firewall/)

Comment: Thanks man, but I didnt manage to get it to work. Would you please instruct me step by step?