# Sharing internet connection from laptop to WiFi router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-vista, wireless-access-point, ics

So I have two WiFi  routers which I currently don't use but would like to use them to share internet connection from my laptop (Vista) to my wifi router to create a wireless signal for devices in my house.

The routers that I've been trying this with are: AirRouter hp and a D-Link dsl 2750b. The interface (router settings) on the AirRouter seems a bit more straightforward.

So my laptop gets a connection from my cellphone. I usb tether it so I use my Android as a modem. The setup I was picture was Android modem  (usb)>>>> laptop (Ethernet cable) >>> wifi router >>>> creates a signal to devices in house.

When I think I get all the settings right in the router and go to share the connection from the network adapter (Android modem) to the local area connection (Ethernet)....it doesn't work.

I disabled the dhcp server on the router settings.

I tried to follow the  instructions on things here: [Setting up wifi router as a switch for Internet Connection Sharing](https://superuser.com/questions/241651/setting-up-wifi-router-as-a-switch-for-internet-connection-sharing)

The only part of the instructions I didn't follow was #7. The WiFi routers don't have a wan port. The AirRouter has 4 lan ports, a USB port and a PoE which acts as a want port in Soho mode and the D-Link dsl router has 4 lan port, a USB port and a dsl port.

I'm using pdanet to share the connection to my laptop. Also when I set all the settings in the router and share the connection I can't get access to the router settings anymore until I reset the router.

I have a luxul xbr 2300 dual wan router sitting around but it doesn't provided a wireless signal.

What am I doing wrong? Please help. Many thanks in advance.